# How can I forward a port using c# and UPNP?

Tags: c#, port, nat, portforwarding, upnp

I want to do UPNP Port Forwarding,
This is my code :

```
NATUPNPLib.UPnPNATClass upnpnat = new NATUPNPLib.UPnPNATClass();
NATUPNPLib.IStaticPortMappingCollection mappings = upnpnat.StaticPortMappingCollection;
mappings.Add(80, "TCP", 80, LocalIP(), true, "Local Web Server");
```

Refrence used for this codes is NATUPNPLib type;
But this code only sometimes work,
Otherwise, returned NULL error for

```
NATUPNPLib.IStaticPortMappingCollection mappings
```

There is no way other than this to port forwarding ??

Error Image Link : http://uploads.im/CLEAF.png

Comment: Maybe port 80 is occupied. Try using some port greater than >1024.

Comment: @Tahlil --> Before adding the port gives error, Because "mappings" is null